# How to get the ASP.NET Menu Control to display a nested list without it's dynamic behavior?

Tags: asp.net, aspmenu-control

Using the ASP.NET Menu control, I would like to have the markup returned be nested unordered lists *without* the dynamic behavior.

In other words, I would like to set my StaticDisplayLevels to the full depth of the datasource, without the resulting markup being a flat list of LI elements.

Yes, I know that I can step in to the DOM and get what I need, but is there no native behavior for this?

```
            <asp:Menu ID="MenuSection" runat="server"                 
                DataSourceID="smdsMenuSection" 
                StaticDisplayLevels="1"
                RenderingMode="List"
                IncludeStyleBlock="False" 
                ClientIDMode="Static"
                SkipLinkText="" 
                >
            </asp:Menu>

            <!-- Sub-navigation Data Source -->
            <asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="smdsMenuSection"  
                StartFromCurrentNode="False" 
                StartingNodeOffset="1"
                ShowStartingNode="True" 
                runat="server" />
```

Comment: I think a treeview could help in this case